# $L^1$ convergence implies pointwise a.e. uniform bound of a subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Is the following statement true ?

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of non-negative functions in $L^1(X,m)$, where $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a probability space, such that $\|f_n - f\|_{L^1(X)}\to 0 $ for some $f \in L^1(X)$. Then there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ and a function $g \in L^1(X,\mu)$ such that
$$f_{n_k}(x) \le g(x) \quad \text{for $\mu$-a.e  } x \in X  .$$

I know that there exists a subsequence that converges almost everywhere, but I don't really know how to use this information. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct even if the functions are not necessarily non-negative. Choose $n_k$ such that $\|f_{n_k} - f \| \le 2^{-k}$ and set 
$$
g = |f| + \sum_{k \ge 0} |f_{n_k}-f| \, 
$$

The sum converges in $L^1$ by the choice of the subsequence, and clearly $f_{n_k} \le g$  for all $k$, since all terms are non-negative.

Comment: Your $g$ is not always in $L^1$. Take $f_n = 1+\frac{1}{n}$ then your $g$ is infinite everywhere.

Comment: You want to choose $f_{n_k}$ such that $\|f_{n_k}- f_{n_{k-1}}\| < 2^{-k}$

Comment: Thank you, I'll modify the answer.